# Grep/awk/sed stateful line matching

Tags: awk, sed, grep, stateful

I have a log file that contains entries that themselves can split across multiple lines, and I want to find all instances of these entries.

For example:

```
AAA normal line
BBB normal line
XXX important line
 important line continuation 1
 important line continuation 2
BBB normal line
 normal line continuation 1
AAA normal line
XXX important line
 important line continuation 1
 important line continuation 2
 important line continuation 3
AAA normal line
```

All entries start with a code (AAA, BBB, XXX etc).  Lines starting with code XXX and their associated continuation lines are the lines I'm interested in. Continuation lines start with a space, and there could be any number of continuation lines. Lines following the continuation lines could start with any code.

I think of this as a kind of 'stateful' matching (although it might not be solved this way)... ie: I want lines matching pattern XXX, then all immediately following lines starting with a space (until they don't).

How can I grep, sed, or awk for this, whilst tailing the log file?

**Update:** Example desired result:

```
XXX important line
 important line continuation 1
 important line continuation 2
XXX important line
 important line continuation 1
 important line continuation 2
 important line continuation 3
```

Comment: What is expected output? Also show your attempt.

Comment: It's quite simple with sed or grep (and probably with awk too, I'm not good with awk). Think about it: you want all lines that begin with "XXX" or " ".

Comment: @Beta No I dont.  For example, I dont want the continuation line following the BBB line.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It's still not too bad in sed, but you should show some attempt at a solution.

Comment: @anubhava Updated with expected output.  I don't know sed, or awk, so no idea whether they have the ability to solve this problem.  There's no way I know of to solve this with grep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` should work:

```
awk '/^[^ \t]/{p = ($1 == "XXX")} p' file
```

```
XXX important line
 important line continuation 1
 important line continuation 2
XXX important line
 important line continuation 1
 important line continuation 2
 important line continuation 3
```

**Command Explanation:**

- `/^[^ \t]/`: Condition, if a line doesn't start with space or tab
- `{`: Start action block
- `p = ($1 == "XXX")`: Set `p` to `1` if first column is `XXX` otherwise set it to `0`.
- `}`: End block
- `p`: If `p==1` then print line

`p` will be set to `1` when we find `$1 == XXX` and we'll keep printing lines until `p` becomes `0` again.

Comment: Thanks, but how does this work?  Reversing this from syntax to sections of the awk user's guide is difficult...  Looks like you've got a regular expression for "lines that begin with something other than a space or tab", then applying an action that says "output lines with first field equal to 'XXX' ".  How does this work to capture the following continuation lines? (again, not knowing awk makes this difficult to grok, appreciate your help).

Comment: Added explanation in answer.

Comment: That final insight of "p: If p==1 then print line" allowed me to understand. Thanks!  Nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^XXX/{:a;n;/^ /ba};d' file
```

If a line begins with `XXX` print it then fetch the next line.

If that line begins with a space print it and fetch the next and repeat.

Any other line will be deleted.

N.B. The `n` normally prints the current line in the pattern space and then replaces it with the next line. This is the normal cycle in sed e.g. `sed '' file` will just print the file. If the `-n` option is used, the implicit print is not done, thus:

```
sed -n '/^XXX/{:a;p;n;/^ /ba}' file
```

achieve the same results.

If the start of the line may be a tab or any white space, use:

```
sed '/^XXX/{:a;n;/^\s/ba};d' file
```

Comment: Yep, that works on linux, thanks!  (not on Mac though which doesn't seem to be using GNU sed, as you noted; `sed: 1: "/^XXX/{:a;n;/^ /ba};d": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)`).